# C# List comparison including duplicate items

Tags: c#, string, list

I need to compare both list considering the duplicate items and return non matching from both lists.

e.g.

Scenario 1 :

```cs
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "L1", "AB", "L1" };
List<string> listB = new List<string> { "L1", "AB" };
```

expected result

```
List<string> result  =  { "L1" };
```

Scenario 2 :

```
List<string> listA = new List<string> { "L1" };
List<string> listB = new List<string> { "L1", "AB", "L1"};
```

expected result

```
List<string> result  =  { "AB", "L1" };
```

I tried below options and none gave me expected result

```
List<string> result = listA.Except(listB).ToList();

List<string> result = listA.Concat(listB).Where(w => !(listA.Contains(w) && listB.Contains(w))).ToList();

List<string> result = listA.Union(listB).Where(w => !(listA.Contains(w) && listB.Contains(w))).ToList();

List<string> result = listA.Union(listB).Except(listA.Intersect(listB)).ToList();
```

Comment: @gunr2171 I think this problem a bit differs from the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Try this: `List<string> common = listA.Union(listB).ToList();  
List<string> left = common.Except(listB).ToList();  
List<string> right = common.Except(listA).ToList();`

Comment: @MaciejLos `Except` is set based operation, it will remove all occurrences of the items.

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, it does, but i think OP is trying to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove each item in `listB` from `listA` and vice-versa then combine the two results. Assuming you don't want to modify `listA` and don't need micro-optimization, you can do:

```
var ans = listA.ToList();
foreach (var r in listB)
    ans.Remove(r);
var leftB = listB.ToList();
foreach (var r in listA)
    leftB.Remove(r);
ans.AddRange(leftB);
```

Comment: @GuruStron From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0): "Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the `List<T>`."

Comment: Yep, my bad, seems that I have confused it with some other operation. Still this will not handle items in B missing from A (i.e. you need to perform something similar with reversed collections and combine the results).

Comment: @GuruStron You are correct, I missed that it needed to be in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0) is a set based operation:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences.
> The set difference of two sets is defined as the members of the first set that don't appear in the second set.

So it excludes all occurrences of items from the second collection.

One approach would be to use dictionaries with counts (e.g. frequencies). Something along these lines:

```cs
var result = new List<string>();
var dictA = listA
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Count());

var dictB = listB
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Count());

foreach (var (key, value) in dictA)
{
    var diff = value;
    if (dictB.TryGetValue(key, out var bCount))
    {
        diff = Math.Abs(diff - bCount);
    }
    result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(key, diff));
}

foreach (var (key, value) in dictB)
{
    if (!dictA.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        result.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(key, value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest computing items' *frequencies* for each list:

```
var freqA = listA
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

var freqB = listB
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

and then combine them: for each value within `listA` or `listB` we compute frequency it should appear in `result`:

```
var result = freqA.Keys
  .Union(freqB.Keys)
  .Select(key => (
     key    : key, 
     countA : freqA.TryGetValue(key, out int countA) ? countA : 0, 
     countB : freqB.TryGetValue(key, out int countB) ? countB : 0))
  .SelectMany(item => Enumerable.Repeat(
     item.key, 
     Math.Abs(item.countA - item.countB)))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: `Math.Max(item.countA, item.countB) -  Math.Min(item.countA, item.countB)` isn't it just `Math.Abs(item.countA - item.countB)` like in my answer?

Comment: @Guru Stron: You are absolutely right, thank you!